# What are the uses of square roots of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication

The question says it all. Are there any theoretical or practical uses of square roots of a matrix? Any algorithm that uses/requires it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Some_applications

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, the square root of a matrix extends the notion of square root from numbers to matrices.

Matrix B is said to be a square root of **A** if the matrix product **BB** is equal to **A**.

For example there is a company that wants to know how much it will incur by using a service, you have your data on a spreadsheet a **transition matrix** (Each of its entries is a nonnegative real number representing a probability) on how the cost changes from one year to another, you be working in eights of a year, so the aim is to find the **eight root of the matrix.**